# SOAP API - CRITICAL: Argument 1 to finfo:buffer() must be of type ?string, bool given (PlentyMarkets)

Tags: php, string, api, soap, buffer

im try to add Images to existing Products via SOAP.
But i always get an error. sometimes after the first loop, or after the tenth loop.

> [CRITICAL] Exception : Argument 1 to finfo::buffer() must be of type ?string, bool given

This is how my code looks like

```
foreach($items as $item) {    

   $image = new PlentySoapRequest_SetItemImages();

   $image->Images->item->ImageURL = $item['url'];
   $image->ItemID = $item['id'];

   $this->getPlentySoap()->SetItemImages($image);

}
```

I dont know what the Problem is. 
Can anyone translate me the error message? or what this error means?

Comment: I know the answer comes kinda late but I had the same problem just now. Problem was that the filename had a space (%20 in the URL). Since the filename appears both in _ImageURL_ and _ImageFileName_ I can't say for sure what causes the mistake but the since you only used the URL I guess it's that.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message means: you gave an boolean argument to the buffer() function, like "buffer(true)", instead of a string value like "buffer('great picture').

There is not much more I can derive from your question, any following stuff and suggestions are just guesswork. Sorry, I should post my "answer" as a comment, but I'm not allowed to add comments.

Looks like you are using Plenty's example PHP-SOAP-Client, and your question implicitly states, that sometimes you can add images to some products. So you could could try to re-run your soap request and see, whether results are reproducible - maybe after removing a successfully added picture before retrying.

tomtomtom

Comment: Well, after adding an answer I can add a comment, too. So some more hints to track down your error:

Comment: Hitting ENTER posted an incomplete comment. Editing took more than 5 minutes, so I couldn't change it any more. So here again: Well, after adding an answer I can add a comment, too. So some more hints to track down your error: 1. most probably you didn't call the buffer function yourself, so find out which part of your code implicitly calls through higher level calls. 2. Can you use other Soap API calls successfully? Does your setup work properly, just not for adding pictures to articles? Ok, enough for now.